# What is the maximum framerate achievable on Android and iOS devices with Unity3d?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I was wondering what is the maximum framerate that could be achieved on iOS and Android devices with Unity3d. Can 60 fps and 100 fps be reached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What FPS should I provide:**

- Android as a platform aims to provide 60fps as a standard. However, keep in mind this is for Applications which come nowhere near the GPU requirements of a game.
- If you can't do all of the calculations you require in 16ms (60fps) you should aim to provide 30fps and provide the user a consistent experience. User's will quickly detect variations in frame rate and interpret this as a performance issue with their phone.
- *Never over-promise and under-deliver.*
- Modern phones claim to have quad core processors with other incredible hardware profiles. Rarely are you taking advantage of the full capabilities of a phone, the hardware and Android platform is designed to use as minimal battery as possible and cut corners when it can.
- Your user's phone is typically idling and the full potential will be activated for a sparing amount of ms to perform work and catch up on operations.

---

**What is the max performance on Android:**

- You can search for Android benchmark test's using Unity, keep a very open mind for what each phone puts through as there are more than 12,000 hardware configurations for Android.
- Your development phone and those for testing should be expected to be significantly better than your user's phones.